# What Payment Gateway providers are available for Sitecore 10?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I'm starting with Sitecore Commerce for Sitecore XP 10.1, I'm confused as to what are the different Payment gateway providers available for Sitecore Commerce other than Braintree?

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stripe other Sitecore Commerce payment provider was develop by XCentium .
More information you can find here:

https://www.xcentium.com/blog/2019/05/14/first-stripe-plugin-for-sitecore-experience-commerce-enables-ach-payments

You can find the source code on github:

https://github.com/xckondapally/SXC.StripePaymentProcessor

@Andrei Paliakou extend the Braintree Payment provider: https://github.com/Frog911/Plugin.Sample.Payments.BraintreeWithMultiCurrencySupport

So you can look on the other example how to integrate with any other payment provider.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vlad for your help :)

Answer (score 6):

As part of the Sitecore.Commerce.SDK, Sitecore XC includes an integration with the BrainTree payment provider and this is the only available Payment gateway provider that comes with OOTB. But You do not need to use BrainTree in a production Sitecore XC implementation. You can remove the BrainTree integration and replace it with your own custom integration or any integration. Sitecore XC is based on plugin architecture so you can simply create your plugin for it.

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav for your helpful answer. The way I get it, anything other than BrainTree will have to be developed separately.

Comment: Yes, then in that case you need to follow above @vlad's links.